# Могу ли я продавать программу, которая использует LGPL библиотеку?

Tags: c#, лицензирование

Могу я продавать свой программный продукт, если использую в нём библиотеку TagLib, для чтения тегов mp3 файлов?

Лицензия у TagLib - LGPL, MPL. Что это значит и какие ограничения подразумеваются, я так и не понял.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы лицензирования выходят за рамки настоящего сайта.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если LGPL библиотека используется в варианте динамической линковки (dll), то исходники вашей программы можно не открывать, если используется статическая линковка, то лицензия требует открыть исходники. Идея, что у пользователя вашей программы должна быть возможность модифицировать LGPL библиотеку самостоятельно. В случае с dll предполагается, что пользователь может ее в будущем подменить на др версию.
Продавать же программу можно в обоих случаях, просто в одном из них нужно предоставлять исходники.

Comment: дополнительная информация содержится на [этой](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/license-list.ru.html) странице. в частности, про [lgpl-2.1](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/license-list.ru.html#LGPLv2.1) и [mpl-1.1](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/license-list.ru.html#MPL), [используемыми проектом taglib](https://github.com/taglib/taglib) (см. файлы `COPYING.LGPL` и `COPYING.MPL`).

Answer (score 1):

По идее если ты не вносишь в либу свои изменения, то всё ок, делай что хочешь. Если в библиотеке появились изменения - будь добр их всем показать)
И `LGPL` разрешает использовать библиотеки в закрытых проектах, когда `GPL` нет. Так что продавайте за здоровье!

Comment: Не совсем так. Если вы статически слинкуете ее с вашей программой, то должны предоставить исходники.